# Inconsistent variable initialization in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, initialization, deterministic

I noticed that even the slightest change to a TensorFlow graph can have a random effect on the result, even though the computation is essentially the same.

In the following example, adding a `tf.no_op` to the graph before adding the variable `y` changes the initial value of that variable:

```
def example(add_no_op=False):
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    tf.set_random_seed(42)

    x = tf.get_variable('x', shape=[], dtype=tf.float32)

    if add_no_op:
        tf.no_op()

    y = tf.get_variable('y', shape=[], dtype=tf.float32)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        print(sess.run([x, y]))
```

```
>>> example()
[0.47769845, 0.014582992]

>>> example(add_no_op=True)
[0.47769845, 0.3524617]
```

This is not what I would expect. With the same random seed, I would expect the same result even if the model is slightly different, as long as the variables are added in the same order and there is no other source of non-determinism.

In general, when I refactor a piece of code, checking that it still produces the same output is a good way to make sure I didn't break it. However, in TensorFlow, this doesn't seem to work.

Why does this happen and how can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: Well I am not sure, but there might be a lot of random seeds that need to be initialized. The numpy seed and the python random seed. Try that and see if it works ?

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya That doesn't work.